ctags works but not for tagbar (C language)
I have a similar situation like this post but I'm working on C.
I have installed ctags on my machine via ctags-nightly-build.
$ which ctags
/usr/local/bin/ctags

$ ctags --version
Universal Ctags 6.1.0(030eca1), Copyright (C) 2015-2023 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Aug  9 2024, 04:31:51
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Output version: 0.0
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +gnulib_fnmatch, +gnulib_regex, +internal-sort, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +yaml, +packcc, +optscript

tagbar is installed via lazy.nvim.
return {
  'preservim/tagbar',
}

I did ctags -R in the working project (directory) and got a tags file.

When I open a .c file, there is no error message popping out.
But when I toggle the tagbar, it shows nothing (in the rightmost window).

Edited
The content of the tags is as follows.
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION anonymous   /Include tags for non-named objects like lambda/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION fileScope   /Include tags of file scope/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION pseudo  /Include pseudo tags/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION subparser   /Include tags generated by subparsers/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION epoch   /the last modified time of the input file (only for F\/file kind tag)/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION file    /File-restricted scoping/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION input   /input file/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION name    /tag name/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION pattern /pattern/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION typeref /Type and name of a variable or typedef/
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    d,macro /macro definitions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    e,enumerator    /enumerators (values inside an enumeration)/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    f,function  /function definitions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    g,enum  /enumeration names/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    h,header    /included header files/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    m,member    /struct, and union members/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    s,struct    /structure names/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    t,typedef   /typedefs/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    u,union /union names/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C    v,variable  /variable definitions/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_EXCMD  mixed   /number, pattern, mixed, or combineV2/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_FILESEP    slash   /slash or backslash/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_VERSION    0.0 /current.age/
!_TAG_PARSER_VERSION!C  1.1 /current.age/
!_TAG_PATTERN_LENGTH_LIMIT  96  /0 for no limit/
!_TAG_PROC_CWD  /home/nfore/Desktop/tst/    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   6.1.0   /030eca1/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!C!function   foreigndecl /declared in foreign languages/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!C!header local   /local header/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!C!header system  /system header/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!C!macro  undef   /undefined/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!C!struct foreigndecl /declared in foreign languages/
f_1 test.c  /^void f_1(){$/;"   f   typeref:typename:void
f_2 test.c  /^void f_2(){$/;"   f   typeref:typename:void
f_3 test.c  /^void f_3(){$/;"   f   typeref:typename:void

Also, the content of tagbardebug.log is as follows.
# Run `:TagbarDebug`, open `test.c` via nvim-tree, `:TagbarToggle`, `:TagbarDebugEnd`, `:q`

NVIM v0.10.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1713484068
Run ":verbose version" for more info1969-12-31 16:09:43.253597: ToggleWindow called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.253801: OpenWindow called with flags: ''
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254005: Checking for Exuberant Ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254342: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254432: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254493: ctags_args (is a string): --version
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254848: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' --version
1969-12-31 16:09:43.254953: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' --version
1969-12-31 16:09:43.258650: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' --version'"
1969-12-31 16:09:43.258743: Exit code: 0
1969-12-31 16:09:43.259628: Command output:
Universal Ctags 6.1.0(030eca1), Copyright (C) 2015-2023 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Aug  9 2024, 04:31:51
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Output version: 0.0
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +gnulib_fnmatch, +gnulib_regex, +internal-sort, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +yaml, +packcc, +optscript

1969-12-31 16:09:43.259770: Exit code: 0
1969-12-31 16:09:43.259904: Checking Exuberant Ctags version
1969-12-31 16:09:43.259992: Found Universal Ctags, assuming compatibility
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260125: Initializing types
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260226: Getting filetypes supported by Exuberant Ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260308: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260380: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260453: ctags_args (is a string): --list-languages
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260657: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' --list-languages
1969-12-31 16:09:43.260757: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' --list-languages
1969-12-31 16:09:43.264796: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' --list-languages'"
1969-12-31 16:09:43.265131: Exit code: 0
1969-12-31 16:09:43.288140: Creating autocommands
1969-12-31 16:09:43.289326: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.290142: Vim filetype: 'c', sanitized filetype: 'c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.290791: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.291619: New file, processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.292267: ProcessFile called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.292797: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.295677: typeinfo for file to process: {'ctagstype': 'c', 'ftype': 'c', 'kinddict': {'p': 2, 'f': 10, 's': 6, 'd': 1, 'e': 4, 'v': 9, 'g': 3, 'h': 0, 't': 5, '?': 11, 'm': 8, 'u': 7}, 'sro': '::', 'createKinddict': function('<SNR>62_createKinddict'), 'getKind': function('<SNR>62_getKind'), 'kind2scope': {'s': 'struct', 'u': 'union', 'g': 'enum', '?': 'unknown'}, 'scope2kind': {'enum': 'g', 'struct': 's', 'union': 'u'}, 'kinds': [{'short': 'h', 'long': 'header files', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'd', 'long': 'macros', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'p', 'long': 'prototypes', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'g', 'long': 'enums', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'e', 'long': 'enumerators', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 't', 'long': 'typedefs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 's', 'long': 'structs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'u', 'long': 'unions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'm', 'long': 'members', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'v', 'long': 'variables', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'f', 'long': 'functions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': '?', 'long': 'unknown', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}]}
1969-12-31 16:09:43.297156: Caching file into: /tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/0.c
1969-12-31 16:09:43.299918: ExecuteCtagsOnFile called [/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/0.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.300318: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.300549: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.300769: ctags_args (is a list): ['--extras=+F', '-f', '-', '--format=2', '--excmd=pattern', '--fields=nksSafet', '--sort=no', '--append=no', '-V', '--language-force=c', '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf']
1969-12-31 16:09:43.301553: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/0.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.302177: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/0.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.310398: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/0.c''"
1969-12-31 16:09:43.310749: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:43.311985: Command output:
1969-12-31 16:09:43.312635:   Option: --language-force=c
  Option: --c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf
Initialize parser: C
Initialize parser: LdScript
enable field "name": yes
enable field "input": yes
enable field "pattern": yes
ctags: cannot open temporary file: /data/local/tmp/tags.2scuOf : No such file or directory

1969-12-31 16:09:43.313174: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:43.313931: Ctags error when processing file
1969-12-31 16:09:43.314609: fileinfo empty after processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.340753: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/__Tagbar__.1]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.341687: Still opening window, stopping processing
1969-12-31 16:09:43.342521: InitWindow called with autoclose: 0
1969-12-31 16:09:43.353642: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/__Tagbar__.1]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.355754: In Tagbar window, stopping processing
1969-12-31 16:09:43.358091: Mapping keys
1969-12-31 16:09:43.360404: InitWindow finished
1969-12-31 16:09:43.360699: Removing fileinfo for [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.360831: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.361080: Vim filetype: 'c', sanitized filetype: 'c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.361199: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.361646: New file, processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.361824: ProcessFile called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.362014: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.363276: typeinfo for file to process: {'ctagstype': 'c', 'ftype': 'c', 'kinddict': {'p': 2, 'f': 10, 's': 6, 'd': 1, 'e': 4, 'v': 9, 'g': 3, 'h': 0, 't': 5, '?': 11, 'm': 8, 'u': 7}, 'sro': '::', 'createKinddict': function('<SNR>62_createKinddict'), 'getKind': function('<SNR>62_getKind'), 'kind2scope': {'s': 'struct', 'u': 'union', 'g': 'enum', '?': 'unknown'}, 'scope2kind': {'enum': 'g', 'struct': 's', 'union': 'u'}, 'kinds': [{'short': 'h', 'long': 'header files', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'd', 'long': 'macros', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'p', 'long': 'prototypes', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'g', 'long': 'enums', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'e', 'long': 'enumerators', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 't', 'long': 'typedefs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 's', 'long': 'structs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'u', 'long': 'unions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'm', 'long': 'members', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'v', 'long': 'variables', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'f', 'long': 'functions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': '?', 'long': 'unknown', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}]}
1969-12-31 16:09:43.363643: Caching file into: /tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/1.c
1969-12-31 16:09:43.365645: ExecuteCtagsOnFile called [/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/1.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.366271: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.366490: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.366684: ctags_args (is a list): ['--extras=+F', '-f', '-', '--format=2', '--excmd=pattern', '--fields=nksSafet', '--sort=no', '--append=no', '-V', '--language-force=c', '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf']
1969-12-31 16:09:43.367273: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/1.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.367555: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/1.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.379237: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/1.c''"
1969-12-31 16:09:43.379528: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:43.381795: Command output:
1969-12-31 16:09:43.381998:   Option: --language-force=c
  Option: --c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf
Initialize parser: C
Initialize parser: LdScript
enable field "name": yes
enable field "input": yes
enable field "pattern": yes
ctags: cannot open temporary file: /data/local/tmp/tags.iaVTIg : No such file or directory

1969-12-31 16:09:43.382126: Exit code: 1
            1969-12-31 16:09:43.382807: Ctags error when processing file
1969-12-31 16:09:43.383102: fileinfo empty after processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.390591: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.390904: Vim filetype: 'c', sanitized filetype: 'c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.391060: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.391361: File data outdated, updating [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.391584: ProcessFile called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.391700: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.392878: typeinfo for file to process: {'ctagstype': 'c', 'ftype': 'c', 'kinddict': {'p': 2, 'f': 10, 's': 6, 'd': 1, 'e': 4, 'v': 9, 'g': 3, 'h': 0, 't': 5, '?': 11, 'm': 8, 'u': 7}, 'sro': '::', 'createKinddict': function('<SNR>62_createKinddict'), 'getKind': function('<SNR>62_getKind'), 'kind2scope': {'s': 'struct', 'u': 'union', 'g': 'enum', '?': 'unknown'}, 'scope2kind': {'enum': 'g', 'struct': 's', 'union': 'u'}, 'kinds': [{'short': 'h', 'long': 'header files', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'd', 'long': 'macros', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'p', 'long': 'prototypes', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'g', 'long': 'enums', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'e', 'long': 'enumerators', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 't', 'long': 'typedefs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 's', 'long': 'structs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'u', 'long': 'unions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'm', 'long': 'members', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'v', 'long': 'variables', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'f', 'long': 'functions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': '?', 'long': 'unknown', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}]}
1969-12-31 16:09:43.393236: Caching file into: /tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/2.c
1969-12-31 16:09:43.395508: ExecuteCtagsOnFile called [/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/2.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.395853: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:43.395893: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:43.395938: ctags_args (is a list): ['--extras=+F', '-f', '-', '--format=2', '--excmd=pattern', '--fields=nksSafet', '--sort=no', '--append=no', '-V', '--language-force=c', '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf']
1969-12-31 16:09:43.396081: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/2.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.396153: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/2.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:43.401735: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/2.c''"
1969-12-31 16:09:43.401862: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:43.402877: Command output:
1969-12-31 16:09:43.402955:   Option: --language-force=c
  Option: --c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf
Initialize parser: C
Initialize parser: LdScript
enable field "name": yes
enable field "input": yes
enable field "pattern": yes
ctags: cannot open temporary file: /data/local/tmp/tags.Atro79 : No such file or directory

1969-12-31 16:09:43.403036: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:43.403220: Ctags error when processing file
1969-12-31 16:09:43.403436: fileinfo empty after processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:43.403548: OpenWindow finished
1969-12-31 16:09:43.403628: ToggleWindow finished
1969-12-31 16:09:47.428247: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.428574: Vim filetype: 'c', sanitized filetype: 'c'
1969-12-31 16:09:47.429278: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.430125: File data outdated, updating [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.430282: ProcessFile called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.430844: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.432434: typeinfo for file to process: {'ctagstype': 'c', 'ftype': 'c', 'kinddict': {'p': 2, 'f': 10, 's': 6, 'd': 1, 'e': 4, 'v': 9, 'g': 3, 'h': 0, 't': 5, '?': 11, 'm': 8, 'u': 7}, 'sro': '::', 'createKinddict': function('<SNR>62_createKinddict'), 'getKind': function('<SNR>62_getKind'), 'kind2scope': {'s': 'struct', 'u': 'union', 'g': 'enum', '?': 'unknown'}, 'scope2kind': {'enum': 'g', 'struct': 's', 'union': 'u'}, 'kinds': [{'short': 'h', 'long': 'header files', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'd', 'long': 'macros', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'p', 'long': 'prototypes', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'g', 'long': 'enums', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'e', 'long': 'enumerators', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 't', 'long': 'typedefs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 's', 'long': 'structs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'u', 'long': 'unions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'm', 'long': 'members', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'v', 'long': 'variables', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'f', 'long': 'functions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': '?', 'long': 'unknown', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}]}
1969-12-31 16:09:47.432656: Caching file into: /tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/3.c
1969-12-31 16:09:47.444890: ExecuteCtagsOnFile called [/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/3.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:47.445625: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:47.445906: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:47.445971: ctags_args (is a list): ['--extras=+F', '-f', '-', '--format=2', '--excmd=pattern', '--fields=nksSafet', '--sort=no', '--append=no', '-V', '--language-force=c', '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf']
1969-12-31 16:09:47.446141: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/3.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:47.446386: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/3.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:47.452540: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/3.c''"
1969-12-31 16:09:47.452635: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:47.454257: Command output:
1969-12-31 16:09:47.454446:   Option: --language-force=c
  Option: --c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf
Initialize parser: C
Initialize parser: LdScript
enable field "name": yes
enable field "input": yes
enable field "pattern": yes
ctags: cannot open temporary file: /data/local/tmp/tags.VI47RI : No such file or directory

1969-12-31 16:09:47.455172: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:47.456050: Ctags error when processing file
1969-12-31 16:09:47.456143: fileinfo empty after processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.357760: ToggleWindow called
1969-12-31 16:09:55.358552: CloseWindow called
1969-12-31 16:09:55.359816: goto_win(): 2wincmd w, 0
1969-12-31 16:09:55.367261: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/__Tagbar__.1]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.367772: In Tagbar window, stopping processing
1969-12-31 16:09:55.375109: AutoUpdate called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.375477: Vim filetype: 'c', sanitized filetype: 'c'
1969-12-31 16:09:55.375614: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.375992: File data outdated, updating [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.376116: ProcessFile called [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.376219: Checking if file is valid [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.377898: typeinfo for file to process: {'ctagstype': 'c', 'ftype': 'c', 'kinddict': {'p': 2, 'f': 10, 's': 6, 'd': 1, 'e': 4, 'v': 9, 'g': 3, 'h': 0, 't': 5, '?': 11, 'm': 8, 'u': 7}, 'sro': '::', 'createKinddict': function('<SNR>62_createKinddict'), 'getKind': function('<SNR>62_getKind'), 'kind2scope': {'s': 'struct', 'u': 'union', 'g': 'enum', '?': 'unknown'}, 'scope2kind': {'enum': 'g', 'struct': 's', 'union': 'u'}, 'kinds': [{'short': 'h', 'long': 'header files', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'd', 'long': 'macros', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'p', 'long': 'prototypes', 'fold': 1, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'g', 'long': 'enums', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'e', 'long': 'enumerators', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 't', 'long': 'typedefs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 's', 'long': 'structs', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'u', 'long': 'unions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': 'm', 'long': 'members', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'v', 'long': 'variables', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 0}, {'short': 'f', 'long': 'functions', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}, {'short': '?', 'long': 'unknown', 'fold': 0, 'stl': 1}]}
1969-12-31 16:09:55.378437: Caching file into: /tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/4.c
1969-12-31 16:09:55.380909: ExecuteCtagsOnFile called [/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/4.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.382006: EscapeCtagsCmd called
1969-12-31 16:09:55.382165: ctags_bin: /usr/local/bin/ctags
1969-12-31 16:09:55.382986: ctags_args (is a list): ['--extras=+F', '-f', '-', '--format=2', '--excmd=pattern', '--fields=nksSafet', '--sort=no', '--append=no', '-V', '--language-force=c', '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf']
1969-12-31 16:09:55.383668: Escaped ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/4.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:55.383717: Executing ctags command: '/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/4.c'
1969-12-31 16:09:55.392418: Executing command: "'/bin/bash' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '--extras=+F' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSafet' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=c' '--c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf' '/tmp/nvim.user/WQcbTd/4.c''"
1969-12-31 16:09:55.392520: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:55.394695: Command output:
1969-12-31 16:09:55.394830:   Option: --language-force=c
  Option: --c-kinds=hdpgetsumvf
Initialize parser: C
Initialize parser: LdScript
enable field "name": yes
enable field "input": yes
enable field "pattern": yes
ctags: cannot open temporary file: /data/local/tmp/tags.nz8Mmd : No such file or directory

1969-12-31 16:09:55.395465: Exit code: 1
1969-12-31 16:09:55.396105: Ctags error when processing file
1969-12-31 16:09:55.396576: fileinfo empty after processing [/home/user/Desktop/tst/test.c]
1969-12-31 16:09:55.397823: goto_win(): 1wincmd w, 0
1969-12-31 16:09:55.398683: CloseWindow finished

Is there something I missed? Could anyone help? Thanks.

Well, use the plugin's issue tracker (and add the content of the tags file to your issue).

Hi @romainl , I'm not sure what is "plugin's issue tracker". Could you elaborate on it?

Could you tell us what is the working directory of Vim (what is the result of the following Vim command:  :pwd?)?

Hi @VivianDeSmedt. The directory is located at /home/user/Desktop/tst and :pwd gives /home/user/Desktop/tst, the same path.

Thanks for the feedback!. When you run the command :tag f_2 does Vim move the cursor to the f_2 implementation?

@VivianDeSmedt Yes! :tag f_1, :tag f_2, and :tag f_3 move the cursor the the f_1, f_2, and f_3 implementations, respectively.

If the "tagbar" in your question is https://github.com/preservim/tagbar, then the plugin’s issue tracker is that way: https://github.com/preservim/tagbar/issues. This has nothing to do with Vim, therefore you should use a more appropriate support channel.

Do you have better result after running the command :TagbarForceUpdate?

Hi @VivianDeSmedt, unfortunately, tagbar is still empty after doing :TagbarForceUpdate.

Given that :tag commands work, this seems likely to be a bug in tagbar. In that case I have to agree that sending them a bug report is probably more likely to lead to a solution.

Is ctags in your $PATH (looking are your console output it seems so)?

@romainl as a reminder: questions about plugins are explicitly on-topic here. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

@VivianDeSmedt Yes, ctags in my $PATH.

Thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem with the last version of tagbar. I don't know how to help you :-/

@VivianDeSmedt Thanks for replying! For now, I have to resolution: 1) reset the linux environment; 2) set let $TMPDIR=$HOME . '/.tmp' in config file before loading plugins. Thanks anyway.

Create a .tmp directory at $HOME/.tmp and put
let $TMPDIR=$HOME . '/.tmp'

in my Neovim config before loading plugins. Then tagbar works.
It seems to be an permission issue with the variable TMPDIR that Vim uses. But for now I have no idea why it occurs the permission issue.

I would make sure that the current working directory of Vim is in the root of your project by running the following command:
:cd %:h

You can automate that using the vim-rooter plugin.
Remark: If ctags is not in your $PATH environment variable you have to setup the g:tagbar_ctags_bin global variable:
let g:tagbar_ctags_bin='/usr/local/bin/ctags'


After openign the file test.c and doing :cd %:h, it shows the result that is same as :pwd. But :TagbarToggle is still empty.
